# How to close and open uiSearchBar on tap?

Tags: swift, uisearchbar

I have been trying to open and close uiSearchBar but it slightly changes its y position, its width change is not consistent at first and it has a counterintuitive animation when triggered. Please try the code below you will see that the initial UI when closed is different than when you close it after opening the searchBar. here are what I see:

when component first lays out subviews:

[image]

When first opening the search

[image]

After closing it

[image]

Here is the code:

viewDidload:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         initSearchCont()
}
```

initSearchCont:

```
func initSearchCont(){
        search.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        search.loadViewIfNeeded()
        search.searchResultsUpdater = self
        search.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        search.searchBar.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = false
        search.searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false      
        search.searchBar.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
        definesPresentationContext = false
        self.view.addSubview(search.searchBar)
        navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
        search.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["All", "Pair", "Odd"]
        search.searchBar.delegate = self
        search.searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()

    }
```

viewDidLayoutSuviews:

```
  override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        search.searchBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: search.isActive ? 400 : 50, height: search.isActive ? 100 : 50)
        search.searchBar.placeholder = search.isActive ? "Search" : nil

    }
```

searchBarDelegates:

```
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        search.searchBar.endEditing(true)
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    
    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

    }
```

Comment: Exactly. Due to your condition: `search.isActive ? 400 : 50` this is happening. At first time your searchbar is never active you have to active it on clicking it. So instead of this, Make condition that if `keyboardActive  ? 400 : 50 `

Comment: You might need to set auto layout constraints on the UISearchBar

Answer (score 0):

It may help you

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    // this line is important
    search.searchBar.layoutIfNeeded()
    search.searchBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: search.isActive ? 400 : 50, height: search.isActive ? 100 : 50)
    search.searchBar.placeholder = search.isActive ? "Search" : nil
}
```

BUT

***I preferred custom implementation***

```
private lazy var searchButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 50, width: 50, height: 50)
    button.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    button.layer.masksToBounds = true
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toggleSearch), for: .touchDown)
    return button
}()

@objc
func toggleSearch() {
    search.isActive.toggle()
    searchButton.isHidden = true
}

func initSearchCont() {
    search.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    search.searchResultsUpdater = self
    search.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    search.searchBar.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = false
    search.searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    search.searchBar.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
    definesPresentationContext = false
    self.view.addSubview(search.searchBar)
    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
    search.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["All", "Pair", "Odd"]
    search.searchBar.delegate = self
    search.searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
    search.searchBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: 0, height: 0)
    view.addSubview(searchButton)
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    let isActive = search.isActive
    search.searchBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: isActive ? 400 : 0, height: isActive ? 100 : 0)
    search.searchBar.alpha = isActive ? 1 : 0
    // custom animation
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    search.searchBar.endEditing(true)
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    searchButton.isHidden = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dispatch on the main thread and it will work